# Trying to show a bokeh plot after saving it throws an error

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I created two kinds of decorations:

```
from bokeh.plotting import show
from bokeh.io import save

def savable(function):
    def wrapper(
            *args,
            save_path: Optional[str] = None,
            **kwargs):
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        if save_path:
            print(f"saved to {save_path}")
            save(result, save_path)
        return result

    return wrapper


def showable(function):
    def wrapper(
            *args,
            show: bool = True,
            **kwargs):
        result = function(*args, **kwargs)
        if show and result is not None:
            show(result)
        return result

    return wrapper
```

I decorated some functions that returns a bokeh figure with the two of them.
when the order was:

```
@showable
@savable
```

I got the error
`Models must be owned by only a single document`

I tried changing the order to:

```
@savable
@showable
```

and there was no error.

I need the option to show a plot after saving it so I'm trying to understand why it didn't work in the initial order.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using some models more than one time (e.g. Title) and this leads to the error.

I want to quote from this [question](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/easier-way-to-avoid-models-must-be-owned-by-only-a-single-document-linearaxis-id-7854-is-already-in-a-doc/6041).

> Hard to say anything specific without seeing the actual notebook. Some generic advice:
>
> - Don’t reuse variables
> - Don’t reuse Bokeh models between documents
> - Don’t create models at the top level of a cell. Instead, wrap them all in a function and call that function (similar to how bokeh serve does it internally)

The truth is, that the call `save` and `show` can have a conflict. If you make sure, you only save a figure, if it is not shown in the notebook, then its working.

I suggest to implement only on wrapper like below:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
from bokeh.io import export_png, export_svgs, output_file, reset_output, save

def output_helper(function):
    def wrapper(
            *args,
            show_plot: bool = True,
            save_path: str = None,
            **kwargs):
        p = function(*args, **kwargs)
        if save_path and save_path.endswith('png'):
            export_png(p, filename=save_path)
        elif save_path and save_path.endswith('html'):
            output_file(save_path, mode="inline")
            if not show_plot:
                save(p, filename=save_path, title="Plot", resources=None)
        if show_plot:
            output_notebook()
            show(p)
            reset_output()
        return p

    return wrapper
```

and an example for the usage could be

```
@output_helper
def create_plot():
    p = figure()
    p.circle([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
    return p

create_plot(save_path='a.html')
```

which shows the figure in the notebook and creates a html-file.